# Border is 1px less in Firefox than in other browsers

Tags: css, firefox, firebug, border

I'm adding border and border radius to a div, however the border shows differently in firfox. In firebug, I can see the border is 5px, but in Layout panel, it became 4px. Could you kindly let me know why and hopefully a fix? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: provide html code or css or jsfiddle link

Comment: HI i will try this code but nothing wrong this http://tinkerbin.com/cbdu3MeW

Comment: Please add fiddle so we can have a look at html and css.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I tested the code in jsfiddle and it shows correctly, also if I open the html as a file it's correct, only when I open the page on localhost, it still shows 4px instead of 5px. Not sure why but I'll leave it alone at first, thank you guys!

Comment: If the actual border is correct but reported incorrectly in Firefug, then it sounds like it might be a bug in firebug rather than Firefox itself? Recent versions of Firefox have a built-in dev tools feature, which can also show this info. Press [key:ctrl]+[key:shift]+[key:s] and look at the box model info there... does it show the same values as firebug?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem. Reset the browser's zoom level.